# How to create unique values per group?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column with postcodes where several rows can have the same postcode. I would like to create a unique value which takes the postcode value and adds an underscore followed by a number where this number increases if more than one row belongs to the same postcode.

Easier to show with an example methinks:

[image: Postcodes]

Is this easily done using an expression or macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do it with a formula:

`=A3&"_"&COUNTIF($A$1:A3,A3)`

`COUNTIF($A$1:A3,A3)` simply counts occurrences of value in the first column above the current row.

Improved formula to manage empty rows: `=IF(A3="","",A3&"_"&COUNTIF($A$1:A3,A3))`

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Many thanks for your quick answer :)